# Checking if a string is palindrome

Tags: python, string, palindrome

So i'm trying to write a function that checks if a string is palindrome or not ( palindrome if it spells the same backwards *e.g.: hannah*)

This is a solution i saw online and i don't quite understand it, any simple explanation would be appreciated

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    left_pos = 0
    right_pos = len(string) - 1
    
    while right_pos >= left_pos:
        if not string[left_pos] == string[right_pos]:
            return False
        left_pos += 1
        right_pos -= 1
    return True
    
print(isPalindrome('hannah'))
```

**Edit**: Sorry for my lack of clarity, i mostly dont understand the condition set in the while loop and the logic behind the if statement.

Comment: which part of it dont you understand?

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Everything in it is very basic.

Comment: `not x == y` is an awkward and uncommon way of writing `x != y`. (It's the same as `not (x == y)`, not `(not x) == y`, due to the low precedence of `not`.)

Comment: If string is = 'racecar'.   you try to start comparing with s[0] with s[-1] and progressing from that...  You can visually see what's happening by run this program in https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Note that this won't report `'Hannah'` as being a palindrome, as `'H'` is not equal to `'h'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compares the last character with the first and moves inside the string as follows:

```
hannah
^    ^
```

check the two letters are equal: (return False if not)
move the index by 1

```
hannah
 ^  ^
```

Do the same check

```
hannah
  ^^
```

right index = left index at this point

return True in this case